# Impact of changing Exchange Alias

Tags: exchange

We migrated some time ago from Exchange 2003 to Exchange 2010.

Older users have user login names like FirstNameLastInitial and Exchange aliases that match.

New users, since the migration, have login names as above but aliases as Firstname.Lastname.

All users have a primary email address like Firstname.Lastname@mydomain.com.

I'd very much like to tidy it up - what are the potential problems that might arise from changing the older aliases to Firstname.Lastname? We don't use POP connectors. We do use OWA / ActiveSync.